# Generate ODT documents with dynamic images in PHP

Tags: php, openoffice.org, opendocument

I maintain a couple of web databases based on PHP and mySQL on a shared hosting package.
The databases have a mechanism for the user to upload OpenOffice documents with placeholders:

```
[person.name] [person.address] [person.postcode]
```

I then use [this great PHP tool](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/tbsooo.php) to run through the OpenOffice document and insert values from the database into it. The result is again, an OpenOffice document.

What it can't do is **dynamic images**.

Does anybody know a - preferably PHP-only - solution to insert images into OpenOffice documents?

- I know [PUNO](http://puno.sourceforge.net/install.html). Can't use it in this context because it's shared hosting.
- I know OpenOffice can be run as a daemon - ditto.
- I know [phpDocWriter](http://phpdocwriter.sourceforge.net/). It was great for SXW files but is dead now.
- I know OpenDocument is a collection of XML files in a ZIP file. I once tried to programmatically add a caption to every image in a ODT document. It drove me *fricking crazy*. I look with admiration upon developers who work with the format, but it's not for me.

I would really appreciate any hints on existing solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [odtPHP](http://www.odtphp.com/) might be what you're looking for

is seems to be able to insert images on a placeholder in the document and reads simply from an array to see which image to place.

http://www.odtphp.com/index.php?i=tutorials&p=tutorial5

Now, if you do this as a post-process after your current code, or simply use it instead of TBS, you got everything you need IMHO

Alternatively, you can include a default image with a certain filename in your document, and simply replace that imagefile in the archive.

Comment: Pekka, wouldn't it be a better solution than that `AddFileToDoc` I mentioned? It looks better to me. I wasn't aware of odtPHP. Good to know about it. Thanks alexanderpas!

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of TbsOOo, it's [OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) and it has a feature for inserting/changing a picture in the file.

http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the `AddFileToDoc` method to add an image to the document?

The documentation on this method is here:

http://www.tinybutstrong.com/tbsooo.php#AddFileToDoc

Comment: No, the function only introduces a file into the OpenDocument file (which is a renamed ZIP file). But following that I looked at the XML code for an image, which should be very easy to replace using a DOM parser, I think this will work. Thanks!